# How to access value in the JS file which is stored using php function

Tags: php, wordpress

I am building a custom plugin for a chatbot in wordpress where I have written some logic in the JS file for fetching the API and response. And as a body, I am sending two parameters. Now one of these parameter is  stored in the wp database using php function (my core plugin file). So i want to access the function/that value in my JS file in order to send it in the api request

JS function -

```
fetch('https://whatgpt.up.railway.app/api/query-train-gpt', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        query: userMessage,
        number: phoneNumber,

      }),
    })
```

php function in the backend -

```
function get_admin_phone_number()
{
  // Retrieve the stored admin phone number from the database.
  $admin_phone_number = get_option('admin_phone_number', ''); // Provide a default value if the option is not set.

  // Return the admin phone number.
  return $admin_phone_number;
}
```

Comment: Such JS customization is usually done by adding "inline script", https://digwp.com/2019/07/better-inline-script/

Comment: So then you likely need to make another request to your PHP backend first, to get the data, before you then send the request to the external API. You want something from a server, or to send something to a server? You make a fetch() request. From the client-side, the basic process is the same, whether the request is to your own server or someone else's. Or, if the JS script is within a .php file, and the value is fixed for the duration of the page's lifetime, you can potentially echo it into the script as a hard-coded value when the .php page is being generated.